# Protractor failing to start in docker container

Tags: docker, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

When running my protractor tests inside a docker container they attempt to start and error. I am using docker compose and have tried adjusting the shared memory allocation in each way described in other solutions (ranging all the way up to 8gb allocation on each type). I have attempted using a previously working setup of chrome version and chromedriver (Last working pipeline was on chromedriver_76.0.3809.12 and google-chrome-stable (77.0.3865.75-1)). My current chrome and chromedriver versions are:

```
google-chrome-stable (77.0.3865.90-1)
chromedriver_77.0.3865.40 (the stack trace is from a different run with the same results)
```

```
Running against http://0.0.0.0:8080 with account code: fakecustomer1
[22:05:14] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864}),platform=Linux 4.9.184-linuxkit x86_64)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.findElement(By(css selector, *[id="username"]))
    at onPrepare (/tests/dev_e2e_conf.js:69:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
    at onPrepare (/tests/dev_e2e_conf.js:69:61)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
[22:05:14] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
```

For contrast when run with the same chrome version (osx based instead of linux) and same chrome driver on my local machine they run fine.

Edit: It turns out that it was the application attempting to load angularJS recursively and eventually crashing the tab in the tests (discovered by serving in the docker image and hitting the urls) I still don't know why there was a difference between serving on OS X (where it does not encounter the same error with the same built content and versions) vs Linux.

Answer (score 0):

When running tests, you have to consider:
- selenium containers: hub + browser nodes are running in their own 'NAT' network.
so they have own context and passing url should be with 'external' network or do 'bridge' network so they can access your host network and resolve the local IP.
- protractor instance run in other context: can be a container, other machine, or the local host.

So be sure you are providing the proper IP's for URL you wish to test and the selenium hub.

Comment: This setup worked in previous pipelines and none of the networking has changed. And for reference this service is running on localhost(0.0.0.0) port 8080 of the container and protractor is being run from the same container targeting said node server.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 specifies all IP addresses on all interfaces. Check for proper network mapping over the containers. And use proper addresses host: localhost ip: 127.0.0.1

Comment: Made the suggested changes with no difference